# Pass data attribute from button to textarea in bootstrap modal not working when tinymce enabled

Tags: jquery, tinymce, bootstrap-modal, textarea

i have to pass data from button data attributes to textarea in bootstrap, textarea is tinymce enabled. problem is every other data is showing in modal just textarea data is not showing, when i disable tinymce, i can see that it works in normal textarea.

i have created a fiddle, try to remove the tinymce part, it will work there and when we add tinymce again, it doesn't work.

here is my javascript part

```js
 tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        height: 300
         }); 
  



$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function() {
                            var id = $(this).data('id');
                            var tourid = $(this).data('tourid');
                            var city = $(this).data('city');
                            var day = $(this).data('day');
                            var daydetails = $(this).data('dd');
                            var remarks = $(this).data('remarks');
                            $(".modal-body #dayidn").val(id);
                            $(".modal-body #touridn").val(tourid);
                            $(".modal-body #daynon").val(day);
                            $(".modal-body #citydetn").val(city);
                            $('.modal-body').find('#detailsofday').html(daydetails);
                            $(".modal-body #remarksn").val(remarks);
                     
                             $('#myModalupdate').modal('show');
                            //tinyMCE.get("editor").focus();
                        });
```

```css
.text-blue{
    float: left!important;
    padding: 10px 90px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.0.14/tinymce.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="650" data-tourid="80" data-day="Day 1" data-city=" Ho Chi Minh City" data-dd="<p>Welcome to Saigon! You will be met at the airport and transferred to your hotel. Saigon is a bustling, dynamic and industrious urban center. It is the largest city in Vietnam, the economic capital and the cultural trendsetter whilst within the teeming metropolis are the timeless traditions and beauty of an ancient culture.&nbsp;</p>" data-remarks="Overnight: Ho Chi Minh City" class="open-AddBookDialog text-blue pull-right tips" title="Edit Day"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>Click me</a>


                   
                   <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalupdate" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                        
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header" style="padding:10px 50px;">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Add/Edit Day</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 25px;">


                                    <form role="form" id="itineraryupdate" name="itineraryupdate">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="tourid" id="touridn" value="">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="dayidn" value="">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Day No#</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="day" id="daynon" value="" placeholder="Enter day No">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Heading/City</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cityhead" id="citydetn" value="" placeholder="Enter city/title">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Day Details</label>
                                            <textarea name="daydetails" id="detailsofday"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Remarks/Overnight</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control" id="remarksn" value="" placeholder="Enter remarks">
                                        </div>

                                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Submit</button>
                                    </form>



                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: changing textrea name="tinymce" made it work for me.

Comment: @Lori: i have tried, it didn't work, but what is the logic behind this,

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your question.  Why not treat the textarea as you did every other area?

Comment: well i have tried that first and it didn't worked then i tried this. it didn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your jQuery function is attempting to set the HTML content of the textarea *after* TinyMCE has already initialized.

To set the HTML content in TinyMCE, you can use the `.setContent()` method:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

I have created a Tiny Fiddle example based on your code showing `.setContent()` in action:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/PPgaab

The most relevant part is:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function() {
    var daydetails = $(this).data('dd');
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(daydetails)
    $('#myModalupdate').modal('show');
});
```